# `NullPointerException` thrown while searching text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

First, I keep getting a NullPointerException on the line I put in ** below.
Second, my program is giving the wrong output (I somehow got it to work but then it went back to error). It must be a logic error. I have a file directory.txt of 11 lines, each with a name on it. When I run my program to try to find a certain name, it only finds the first name on the first line and everything else, it can't find. How can I fix these 2 errors?

I have 2 classes. This is the first class Directory:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Directory {
   //public static void main(String[] args) {
   final int maxDirectorySize = 1024;
   String directory[] = new String[maxDirectorySize];
   int directorySize = 0;
   File directoryFile = null;
   Scanner directoryDataIn = null;

   public Directory(String directoryFileName) {
      directoryFile = new File(directoryFileName);
      try {
         directoryDataIn = new Scanner(directoryFile);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("File is not found, exiting!" + directoryFileName);
         System.exit(0);
      }
      while (directoryDataIn.hasNext()) {
         directory[directorySize++] = directoryDataIn.nextLine();
      }
   }
   public boolean inDirectory(String name) {
      boolean inDir = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         **if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name))** 
            inDir = true;
         else 
            inDir = false;
      }
      return inDir;
   }
   public boolean add(String name) {
      if (directory.length == 1024)
         return false;
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return false;
         else
            directory[directorySize++] = name;
            return true;
      }
      return false;
   }          

   public boolean delete(String name) {
      for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
         if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            directory[i] = null;
            return true;
         }   
         else
            return false;
      }
      return false;
   }

   public void closeDirectory() {
      directoryDataIn.close();
      PrintStream directoryDataOut = null;
      try {
          directoryDataOut = new PrintStream(directoryFile);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.printf("File %s not found, exiting!", directoryFile);
         System.exit(0);
      }
      String originalDirectory[] = {"Mike","Jim","Barry","Cristian","Vincent","Chengjun","susan","ng","serena"};
      if (originalDirectory == directory)
         System.exit(0);
      else
         for (int i = 0; i < directorySize; i++)
            directoryDataOut.println(directory[i]);
         directoryDataOut.close();
   }
}
```

AND this is my second class which I'm trying to run but I keep getting exception main thread NullPointerException.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DirectoryWithObjectDesign {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   String directoryDataFile  = "Directory.txt";
   Directory d = new Directory(directoryDataFile);
   Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Directory Server is Ready!");
   System.out.println("Format: command name");
   System.out.println("Enter ^Z to end");
   while (stdin.hasNext()) {
      String command = stdin.next();
      String name = stdin.next();
      if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("find")) {
         if (d.inDirectory(name))
            System.out.println(name + " is in the directory");
         else 
            System.out.println(name + " is NOT in the directory");
      }
      else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
         if (d.add(name))
            System.out.println(name + " added");
         else 
            System.out.println(name + " cannot add! " + "no more space or already in directory");
      }
      else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
         if (d.delete(name))
            System.out.println(name + " deleted");
         else
            System.out.println(name + " NOT in directory");
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("bad command, try again");
      }
   }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your program? Where is the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Check the line number that is throwing the NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
  while (directoryDataIn.hasNext()) {
     directory[directorySize++] = directoryDataIn.nextLine();
  }
```

will only fill up as much of `directory` as there are lines in the input file (11 according to your question).

This code:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
     **if (directory[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name))**
```

will loop over every entry in `directory`, up to its length (1024).

Since 1013 of those entries are `null`, trying to run `equalsIgnoreCase()` on them will result in a NPE.

### Edit

You can solve this one of several ways.  For instance, you could

- keep track of the number of lines you read, and only read up to that point
- check each entry to see if it is `null` before evaluating it
- use a dynamically sized data structure instead of an array, such as `ArrayList`
- perform the check on the known value (e.g. `if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(directory[i]))`)
- etc.

Comment: I kind of see what you're trying to say...how can I fix this though? I need the equalsIgnoreCase in order to see if a name is in the directory... @azurefrog

Comment: I got rid of the NPE error but still getting the logic error...so even if a name is in the text file, it keeps returning the name is not in the directory. Any idea why?

Comment: it's just really weird. sometimes I get the NPE error and other times I don't.  have no idea how to fix it or why it only comes sometimes..

Comment: You loop through the entire array even if you find a match part way through.  If you don't stop after you've found the match, the next thing you check might not be, and so will change `inDir` back to false.  You need to `break` or `return` after you find what you're looking for.

Comment: Regarding an intermittent NPE, without seeing the code you're now using, I can't hazard a guess why.  If you edit your original question to add a follow-up regarding the updated code, I will attempt to help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for (int i = 0; i < directory.length; i++) {
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < directorySize; i++ ){
```

directorySize is already Keeping track of the number of entries so any array entries above that will be null. Therefore trying to call equalsIgnoreCase() on them will get a NPE.

Actually this looks like a prime use for ArrayList rather than array. The list will expand as you need it and List.size() will give you the correct length.

Comment: What is wrong with this?

Comment: Did you try to compile it?

Comment: No it was just  a code snippet to point out where i thought the problem was. I'm sorry about the () I'm trying to help and was typing on a tablet. And all I got was "abuse". I'm new to this answering questions. If I had enough reputation I would probably just have commented but if my answers get voted down so badly I will never get any.  Seems like a good way to make sure the community stagnates if you treat newbys this harshly.

Comment: Instead of answering you, what is wrong with it, I ask you: how is that answer helpful? You're suggesting to use a completely new method `directorySize` without explaining what it should do. Then you're suggesting to use an `ArrayList` instead of an array, without explaining how to do that. Since you have problems to use the `List` API (because you obviously meant `directory.size()`) it is clear, that you haven't thought that through. I suggest to delete that answer, fix the issue and provide an example on how to use a list instead of an array. Then you can undelete it.

Comment: No the () was not meant to be there sorry. I meant the field directorySize which is already keeping track of the number of entries that have been added. The reference to ArrayList was an alternative suggestion that I'll admit I didn't fully explain. But I meant replace the array with a list in that case. I would have expected that if it wasn't understood a comment would have been added not just vote down without any reason.

Comment: Ah ok. And btw if you suggest such changes, you could/should explain why this can help here, so that OP and later readers understand your suggestion better. And mind that StackOverflow doesn't notice the downvoters, so they maybe never see, that you've fixed your answer. Therefore it is possible that the remaining two downvote will stay here. But don't see that as some kind of abuse. At the time of the downvote your answer wasn't helpful due to the syntax error.

Comment: Yeah possibly being a bit sensitive but not knowing why I had such a reaction it was hard to know how to behave in future.

Comment: Asking in the comment where the problem is, like you did, could be the first reaction on that. And before posting some kind of code, it is a good idea to test it first. For example by creating a small project on your PC (or somewhere else) and then applying your suggested fix, to see if there is any syntax error. And checking other answers might help in such cases. Sometimes you see then there the issue in your answer was. But first of all: keep cool :). An abuse is very rare and if you get a lot of downvotes, you still can delete your answer and you will get your reputation back.